# Level set of a convex function itself convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to see how is a level set of a convex function itself convex.

The level set is defined as $$L_c(f)=\{x|f(x)=c\}$$ (see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LevelSet.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) for the definitions)

So, to show that a set is convex, we need to show that if $x,y\in L_c(f)$ then it implies that $\alpha x +(1-\alpha)y\in L_c(f)$.

However I am confused at to how this is possible, since if we take the well-known convex function $x_2$, and we take the level set $L_c(x^2)=\{-2,2\}$, then how is it possible that for all $\alpha\in (0,1), \alpha(-2)+(1-\alpha)(2)\in\{-2,2\}$, since if $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ we have that $\frac{1}{2}(-2)+\frac{1}{2}(2)=-1+1=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, a level set defined like this need not be convex. But the set

$$\{ x : f(x) \leqslant c \}$$

will always be convex provided that $f$ is convex.